# "Битая" ссылка в справке

Tags: дефект, справка, ссылки

В разделе [Какие браузеры поддерживаются?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) [ссылка на визуализацию](https://browserl.ist/?q=last%202%20versions%2C%20not%20ie%20%3C%2011%2C%20not%20dead%2C%20not%20op_mini%20all%2C%20not%20baidu%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_ff%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_qq%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20kaios%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20op_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20ie_mob%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20and_uc%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Samsung%20%3E%200%2C%20not%20Android%20%3E%200) ведёт на страницу-заглушку:

> [image: Browserslist website is down]

Comment: Надо взять с SO, там норм https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support